# Fazer click da UL em A

Tags: jquery

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
<div class="submenu">
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="btn-submenu btn-submenu-xstore"></div>
        <a href="/plataforma-de-ecommerce">xStore - Plataforma de E-commerce</a>
        <div class="submenuDescription">Tecnologia para a realização de vendas de forma prática, segura e completa.</div>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="btn-submenu btn-submenu-b2b"></div>
        <a href="/plataforma-de-ecommerce/b2b">E-commerce B2B Customizado</a>
        <div class="submenuDescription">Solução para vendas a atacado (B2B) destinada à indústrias, distribuidoras, importadoras e atacadistas.</div>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="btn-submenu btn-submenu-marketplace"></div>
        <a href="/plataforma-de-ecommerce/marketplace">Marketplace (Shopping Virtual)</a>
        <div class="submenuDescription">Plataforma de e-commerce para a operação de múltiplas lojas.</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Gostaria que quando eu clicasse na **ul** ele desse o click no **a**, que fica dentro dessa **ul**.

Fiz assim, e não deu certo:

```
$("submenu.ul").click(function{ $(".submenu a").trigger("click"); })
```

Comment: Você não pode por o <a> sobrepondo a <ul>? Seria mais fácil você colocar o <a> englobando toda a <ul>

Comment: Não fui eu que montei a estrutura. Para não perder a estilização, prefiro fazer algo em JQuery.

Comment: Tudo bem. Só comentei devido a parecer se algo simples. Acredito que as respostas contidas resolvem seu problema @FelipeStroker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abaixo coloquei o código e os comentários para a ação que precisa. Mas não recomendo a fazer isso, pois, dentro do ul você poderia ter diversos "a". Ai neste caso, poderia gerar inconsistência na ação dos cliques.

```js
$(function() {

  // Pega o evento do clique dentro do ul
  $(".submenu ul").click(function(e) {
  
    // Dispara o clique no a dentro deste ul
    $(this).find('a').click();
    
  })
  
  // Pega o evento do clique dentro do ul o item a
  $(".submenu ul a").click(function(e) {
  
    // Evita que o evento crie um loop infinito
    e.stopPropagation();
    
    // Pega o link do a
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    
    // Muda de página para o link a
    window.location.href = link;
    
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="submenu">
<ul>
<li>
    <div class="btn-submenu btn-submenu-xstore"></div>
    <a href="/plataforma-de-ecommerce">xStore - Plataforma de E-commerce</a>
    <div class="submenuDescription">Tecnologia para a realização de vendas de forma prática, segura e completa.</div>
</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>
    <div class="btn-submenu btn-submenu-b2b"></div>
    <a href="/plataforma-de-ecommerce/b2b">E-commerce B2B Customizado</a>
    <div class="submenuDescription">Solução para vendas a atacado (B2B) destinada à indústrias, distribuidoras, importadoras e atacadistas.</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Ele faz o click, mas não nesse <a href="/plataforma-de-ecommerce/b2b">

Comment: @FelipeStoker, no seu exemplo só tem este elemento "a". Informe corretamente na sua questão e todo o código, do contrário é impossível saber realmente o que deseja.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta.

Comment: Atualizei o código, veja se é isso.

Comment: Agora funcionou.

Comment: Ok, fico em feliz em ter conseguido ajudado. Agora uma observação, sempre que fizer uma pergunta, coloque o código completo para resolução do problema.

Answer (score 2):

Assim é para funcionar Jovem :
A primeira linha detecta um clique no seletor :

> submenu.ul

E então simula um clique nesse teu elemento :

> .submenu a

```
$(document).on('click','submenu.ul', function(e){
    $(".submenu a").click();
});
```

Comment: Assim não funcionou.

Comment: O que acontece? Veja se não aparace algo no console.

Answer (score 2):

Você tem que definir uma fução para callback.

> Exemplo:

```
$(".submenu ul").click(function() {
      $(this).find('a').trigger("click");
});
```

> Estrutura do HTML:

```
<ul>
 <li class="submenu">
  <ul>
    <li>
        <div class="btn-submenu btn-submenu-b2b"></div>
        <a href="/plataforma-de-ecommerce/b2b">E-commerce B2B Customizado</a>
        <div class="submenuDescription">Solução para vendas a atacado (B2B) destinada à indústrias, distribuidoras, importadoras e atacadistas.</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```